# Как взять название файла и записать его в переменную? Чтобы потом сравнивать эту длину

Tags: linux, c

Удалить обычные файлы (regular file), длина которых совпадает с названием файла (в случае, если
название файла – это целое неотрицательное число).

Comment: Видимо, Вам нужно что-то типа [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4204758) на _en_SO_. Конечно, Вам надо по дороге еще как-то узнавать размер файла (например, через `stat()/fstat()`).

Comment: @Vladimir я правильно понимаю задание, у меня есть дирректория в которой создан файл с названием 5, потом я запускаю этот файл и если в дирректории есть файлы с длиной названия 5 я удаляю их

Comment: Ну, задание-то Вам давал не я, поэтому мое понимание может и отличаться от авторского ;-). А я его так понимаю, что имя файла (если оно задано числом, т.е. полностью конвертируется из строки в число) надо сравнивать с длиной самого файла (т.е. сколько содержимое этого файла занимает места). Таким образом, если Вы нашли _регулярный_ (это Вы тоже должны проверять, ибо бывают еще и другие типы файлов в unix) файл с именем "5", то смотрите на размер этого файла "5". И если размер этого файла тоже равен 5, то тогда удаляете именно его же.

Comment: А вообще, по мне - так задание звучит некорректно, т.к. понятия "длина файла" я никогда раньше не встречал. Его можно трактовать и как размер файла, и как длину имени файла (особенно, если хорошенько выпить).

Comment: понял принял, спасибо!